# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined at Object.success

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

im working with vuejs2 and laravel 
i have this vuejs2 code

```
var path = '/project/public/';
new Vue({
el:'#users',
data:{
    message:'',
    test: [1,2,3],  
},
methods:{
    searchData: _.debounce(function(){
        if(this.message != '')
        {
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url: path+'usersearch',
                data: {data:this.message},
                success:function(data)
                {
                    console.log(data[0]['id']);
                      this.test.push(4)
                },
                error:function()
                {
                    console.log("error");
                }
            });
        }
    },1000)
}
})
```

also i have this html code

```
<tr>
    <td v-for='test in test'>@{{test}}</td>
</tr>
```

its working when there is no request send 
and showing me in the html 1 2 3 but when i have request back 
this code only working fine

```
console.log(data[0]['id']);
```

but this one

```
this.test.push(4)
```

send me back this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined     at Object.success
```

how can i add something to vuejs2 array 
thanks

Comment: Use an arrow function or `bind`.

Comment: could you wright the full code please

Comment: `success: (data) => { … }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize it to empty array before pushing objects,

```
  this.test = [];
```

EDIT

When using arrow function, the this property is not overwritten and still references the component instance.

```
 success:(data) => {
    console.log(data[0]['id']);
    this.test.push(4)
 }
```

Comment: i have the same error

Comment: This is wrong. `test: [1, 2, 3]` -- it's already initialized.

Comment: @Li357 yes corrected

Comment: i need to push data to the array test using vuejs2 its  dos not matter if there data inside the array or not

Comment: its worked thanks alot

Comment: @AwarPulldozer cool! initially i did not realize its vue.

Comment: @Sajeetharan Yes, but you initially had the wrong answer. It would be best if at this point you just use your gold badge to mark it as duplicate